# Zero Topological entropy with nowhere dense periodic points, then exist a $g$ with trajectory approximable by cycles

Tags: analysis, reference-request, entropy, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

In the [article](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1986-297-01/S0002-9947-1986-0849479-9/S0002-9947-1986-0849479-9.pdf) *Chaotic Functions with Zero Topological Entropy* by Jaroslav Smítal, in the **Remark 2.6** the autor cite the following result,

> If $f\in C^0 (I,I)$ has zero topological entropy, and the set of periodic points is closed and [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set), then for any given $\varepsilon>0$, every $g\in C^0 (I,I)$ sufficiently near to $f$ has only trajectories $\varepsilon$-approximable by cycles.

And then conjecture that the result could be valid if the periodic points form a nowhere dense set, that is, it is not necessary for this set to be closed.

This is a 1986 article, and I would like to know if there has been any progress on this *conjecture*, even some discussion about it, I researched and read some articles and found nothing about it, would anyone have any knowledge about the situation of this result?

---

**Edit:**

Following the author's notation (in other articles), it is possible to rewrite the statement he makes as,

> If $f\in C^0(I,I)$ has zero topological entropy and the set of periodic points is nowhere dense, then $f$ is stable.

Remembering that $f$ is nonchaotic and for reference to the definition of stable see [Definition 2.1](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1989-313-02/S0002-9947-1989-0997677-9/S0002-9947-1989-0997677-9.pdf).